# Cannot get ASP.Net to serve any pages under IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

I am trying to set up another instance of a live website for a customer to evalulate, however i am unable to get the server to serve up any ASP.NET pages at all.

I know this is normally a bit of a noob question, but i have set up these servers a hundred times and know all the usual gotchas, i have done all of the following to no avail, and for my example i have created a simple test page that writes out hello world, and i'm still unable to get anything to serve..

This is windows server 2003 R2 SPII

- **I have registered ASP.NET using aspnet_regiis.exe -i**
- **I have enabled the web service extensions**
- **I have created it as a virtual directory, and created the application**
- **I have set the version of ASP.NET for my virtual directory to use**
- **I have even created a new App Pool and given it administrator permissions.**
- **I have run [Auth Diag From Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e90fe777-4a21-4066-bd22-b931f7572e9a), i get and error from the authentication check, but it is blank**
- **I have given full control to the `everyone` group for the folder**
- **I have tried creating a new website with a different port, same problem**

In fiddler i get the following repsonse when loading an asp.net page :

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Timestamp: 09:43:01:0634

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

Looking at the IIS logs, i dont see any entries for any of the ASP.NET requests unless i turn on windows authentication, then i see

```
2011-04-12 08:13:23 W3SVC1 10.4.3.16 GET /test/Test.aspx - 80 - 10.2.16.17 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+GTB6.6;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+InfoPath.2;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 401 2 2148074254

2011-04-12 08:13:26 W3SVC1 10.4.3.16 GET /test/Test.aspx - 80 - 10.2.16.17 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+GTB6.6;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+InfoPath.2;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 401 1 0
```

HTML Pages serve up just fine, i'm stumped and about to get the server re-built as i have wasted long enough on this..

Any ideas :( ?

Comment: Have you created an application? http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1c9a73-b4c5-4cfb-ad69-b77fa2e17e19.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: yes, i have created the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing IIS and re-installign it, set the site back up and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the windows event log for information that may lead to what is causing this?

You could also try removing the application role and adding it again encase there was an issue when originally setting it up.